# Anaconda Navigator Updater UnsatisfiableError

Tags: python, python-3.x, anaconda, conda

Trying to update anaconda but keep getting UnsatisfiableError when I do it through the GUI. I've tried launching the Navigator as an admin on Win10. I've searched the internet but no solution works.

I've also tried (with admin privileges prompt) `conda update -n base -c defaults conda` as suggested after running `conda update conda` both of which say `All requested packages already installed` and `==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==`. It's like trying to mock me and such.

I've also tried to disable `ssl_verify` by setting it to false in `condarc`. No difference in any of the above methods.

Trying to update from 1.9.2 to 1.9.6.

#### If I were to install the latest version of anaconda, would that be the same as updating it? Or will I lose my manually installed packages and environments?

Anaconda or Miniconda version: 1.9.2

Operating System: Win10

`conda info`

```
     active environment : base
    active env location : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3
            shell level : 1
       user config file : C:\Users\Chad\.condarc
 populated config files : C:\Users\Chad\.condarc
          conda version : 4.5.11
    conda-build version : 3.11.0
         python version : 3.5.5.final.0
       base environment : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3  (writable)
           channel URLs : https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/pro/noarch
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                          https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
          package cache : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\pkgs
                          C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
       envs directories : C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs
                          C:\Users\Chad\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
                          C:\Users\Chad\.conda\envs
               platform : win-64
             user-agent : conda/4.5.11 requests/2.19.1 CPython/3.5.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
          administrator : True
             netrc file : None
           offline mode : False
```

`conda list --show-channel-urls`

```
# packages in environment at C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3:
#
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
_ipyw_jlab_nb_ext_conf    0.1.0            py35hfaa8434_0    defaults
alabaster                 0.7.11                     py_3    conda-forge
anaconda-client           1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
anaconda-navigator        1.9.2                    py35_0    defaults
anaconda-project          0.8.2                      py_1    conda-forge
appdirs                   1.4.3                      py_1    conda-forge
asn1crypto                0.24.0                   py35_2    conda-forge
astroid                   2.0.2                    py35_0    conda-forge
astropy                   3.0.4                    py35_0    conda-forge
atomicwrites              1.1.5                    py35_0    conda-forge
attrs                     18.1.0                     py_1    conda-forge
automat                   0.7.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.6.0                      py_1    conda-forge
backcall                  0.1.0                      py_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.shutil_get_terminal_size 1.0.0                      py_3    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.6.3                    py35_0    conda-forge
bitarray                  0.8.3            py35hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
bkcharts                  0.2                      py35_0    conda-forge
blas                      1.0                         mkl    defaults
blaze                     0.11.3                   py35_0    conda-forge
bleach                    2.1.4                      py_1    conda-forge
blosc                     1.14.3               he51fdeb_0    defaults
bokeh                     0.13.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
boto                      2.49.0                   py35_0    defaults
bottleneck                1.2.1            py35h452e1ab_1    conda-forge
bzip2                     1.0.6                hfa6e2cd_5    defaults
ca-certificates           2018.03.07                    0    defaults
certifi                   2018.8.24                py35_1    defaults
cffi                      1.11.5           py35hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
chardet                   3.0.4                    py35_3    conda-forge
click                     6.7                        py_1    conda-forge
cloudpickle               0.5.5                      py_0    conda-forge
clyent                    1.2.2                      py_1    conda-forge
colorama                  0.3.9                      py_1    conda-forge
comtypes                  1.1.7                    py35_0    conda-forge
conda                     4.5.11                   py35_0    defaults
conda-build               3.11.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
conda-env                 2.6.0                h36134e3_1    defaults
conda-verify              2.0.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
console_shortcut          0.1.1                h6bb2dd7_3    defaults
constantly                15.1.0                     py_0    conda-forge
contextlib2               0.5.5                      py_2    conda-forge
cryptography              2.3.1            py35h74b6da3_0    conda-forge
cryptography-vectors      2.3.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
curl                      7.60.0               h7602738_0    defaults
cycler                    0.10.0                     py_1    conda-forge
cython                    0.28.5           py35h6538335_0    conda-forge
cytoolz                   0.9.0.1          py35hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
dask                      0.18.2                     py_0    conda-forge
dask-core                 0.18.2                     py_0    conda-forge
datashape                 0.5.4                    py35_0    conda-forge
decorator                 4.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
distributed               1.22.1                   py35_0    conda-forge
docutils                  0.14                     py35_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.2.3                    py35_1    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
fastcache                 1.0.2            py35hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
filelock                  3.0.4                      py_1    conda-forge
flask                     1.0.2                      py_1    conda-forge
flask-cors                3.0.6                      py_0    conda-forge
freetype                  2.8                  h51f8f2c_1    defaults
get_terminal_size         1.0.0                h38e98db_0    defaults
gevent                    1.3a1                    py35_0    conda-forge
glob2                     0.6                        py_0    conda-forge
greenlet                  0.4.13                   py35_0    conda-forge
h5py                      2.8.0            py35hb24199d_1    conda-forge
hdf5                      1.10.2               hac2f561_1    defaults
heapdict                  1.0.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
html5lib                  1.0.1                      py_0    conda-forge
hyperlink                 17.3.1                     py_0    conda-forge
icc_rt                    2017.0.4             h97af966_0    defaults
icu                       58.2                 ha66f8fd_1    defaults
idna                      2.7                      py35_2    conda-forge
imageio                   2.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
imagesize                 1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
incremental               17.5.0                     py_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2018.0.0                      8    defaults
ipykernel                 4.8.2                    py35_0    conda-forge
ipython                   6.5.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
ipywidgets                7.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
isort                     4.3.4                    py35_0    conda-forge
itsdangerous              0.24                       py_2    conda-forge
jdcal                     1.4                        py_1    conda-forge
jedi                      0.12.1                   py35_0    conda-forge
jinja2                    2.10                       py_1    conda-forge
jpeg                      9b                   hb83a4c4_2    defaults
jsonschema                2.6.0                    py35_1    conda-forge
jupyter                   1.0.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_client            5.2.3                      py_1    conda-forge
jupyter_console           5.2.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                0.34.2                   py35_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_launcher       0.13.1                     py_2    conda-forge
keyring                   13.2.1                   py35_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.0.1            py35he980bc4_2    conda-forge
lazy-object-proxy         1.3.1            py35hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
libcurl                   7.60.0               hc4dcbb0_0    defaults
libiconv                  1.15                 h1df5818_7    defaults
libpng                    1.6.34               h79bbb47_0    defaults
libsodium                 1.0.16               h9d3ae62_0    defaults
libssh2                   1.8.0                hd619d38_4    defaults
libtiff                   4.0.9                hb8ad9f9_1    defaults
libxml2                   2.9.8                hadb2253_1    defaults
libxslt                   1.1.32               hf6f1972_0    defaults
llvmlite                  0.23.2                   py35_1    conda-forge
locket                    0.2.0                      py_2    conda-forge
lxml                      4.2.4            py35heafd4d3_0    conda-forge
lzo                       2.10                 h6df0209_2    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libgfortran     5.3.0                         6    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs            5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gcc-libs-core       5.3.0                         7    defaults
m2w64-gmp                 6.1.0                         2    defaults
m2w64-libwinpthread-git   5.0.0.4634.697f757               2    defaults
markupsafe                1.0                      py35_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                2.2.2            py35h153e9ff_1    defaults
mccabe                    0.6.1                      py_1    conda-forge
menuinst                  1.4.14                   py35_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.3            py35hfa6e2cd_2    conda-forge
mkl                       2018.0.2                      1    defaults
mkl-service               1.1.2            py35h051acba_4    defaults
mkl_fft                   1.0.6                    py35_0    conda-forge
mkl_random                1.0.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
more-itertools            4.3.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
mpmath                    1.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
msgpack-python            0.5.6            py35he980bc4_2    conda-forge
msys2-conda-epoch         20160418                      1    defaults
multipledispatch          0.6.0                      py_0    conda-forge
navigator-updater         0.2.1                    py35_0    defaults
nbconvert                 5.3.1                      py_1    conda-forge
nbformat                  4.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
networkx                  2.1                        py_1    conda-forge
nltk                      3.2.4                    py35_0    conda-forge
nose                      1.3.7                    py35_2    conda-forge
notebook                  5.6.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
numba                     0.38.1           py35h830ac7b_0    defaults
numexpr                   2.6.6                    py35_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.14.3           py35h9fa60d3_1    defaults
numpy-base                1.14.3           py35h555522e_1    defaults
numpydoc                  0.8.0                      py_1    conda-forge
odo                       0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
olefile                   0.45.1                     py_1    conda-forge
open3d                    0.3.0                    py35_0    open3d-admin
openpyxl                  2.5.5                      py_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.0.2p               hfa6e2cd_0    defaults
packaging                 17.1                       py_0    conda-forge
pandas                    0.23.4           py35h830ac7b_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    1.19.2.1             hb2460c7_1    defaults
pandocfilters             1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
parso                     0.3.1                      py_0    conda-forge
partd                     0.3.8                      py_1    conda-forge
path.py                   11.0.1                     py_0    conda-forge
pathlib2                  2.3.2                    py35_0    conda-forge
patsy                     0.5.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pep8                      1.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.4                    py35_0    conda-forge
pillow                    5.0.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
pip                       18.0                     py35_1    conda-forge
pkginfo                   1.4.2                      py_1    conda-forge
pluggy                    0.7.1                      py_0    conda-forge
ply                       3.11                       py_1    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
prompt_toolkit            1.0.15                   py35_0    conda-forge
psutil                    5.4.7            py35hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
py                        1.5.4                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1                    0.4.4                      py_0    conda-forge
pyasn1-modules            0.2.1                      py_0    conda-forge
pycodestyle               2.4.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.3            py35hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.18                       py_1    conda-forge
pycrypto                  2.6.1                    py35_1    conda-forge
pycurl                    7.43.0.2         py35h74b6da3_0    defaults
pyflakes                  2.0.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pyglet                    1.2.4                    py35_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pyhamcrest                1.9.0                      py_2    conda-forge
pylint                    2.1.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
pyodbc                    4.0.23           py35h6538335_1    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 18.0.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.9.2            py35h1aa27d4_0    defaults
pyreadline                2.1                      py35_0    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.6.8                    py35_1    conda-forge
pytables                  3.4.4            py35h7e76658_1    conda-forge
pytest                    3.7.2                    py35_0    conda-forge
pytest-arraydiff          0.2                        py_0    conda-forge
pytest-astropy            0.4.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-doctestplus        0.1.3                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-openfiles          0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
pytest-remotedata         0.3.0                      py_0    conda-forge
python                    3.5.5                he025d50_2    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.7.3                      py_0    conda-forge
pytz                      2018.5                     py_0    conda-forge
pywavelets                0.5.2            py35h452e1ab_2    conda-forge
pywin32                   221                      py35_0    conda-forge
pywin32-ctypes            0.2.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
pywinpty                  0.5.4                    py35_1    conda-forge
pyyaml                    3.12                     py35_1    conda-forge
pyzmq                     17.1.2           py35hf576995_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.9.5            vc14he4a7d60_0  [vc14]  defaults
qtawesome                 0.4.4              pyh8a2030e_1    conda-forge
qtconsole                 4.3.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
qtpy                      1.4.2              pyh8a2030e_1    conda-forge
requests                  2.19.1                   py35_1    conda-forge
rope                      0.10.7                     py_1    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.61          py35hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
scikit-image              0.14.0           py35h6538335_1    conda-forge
scikit-learn              0.19.1           py35h2037775_0    defaults
scipy                     1.1.0            py35h672f292_0    defaults
seaborn                   0.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
send2trash                1.5.0                      py_0    conda-forge
service_identity          17.0.0                     py_0    conda-forge
setuptools                40.2.0                   py35_0    conda-forge
simplegeneric             0.8.1                      py_1    conda-forge
singledispatch            3.4.0.3                  py35_0    conda-forge
sip                       4.19.8           py35h6538335_0    conda-forge
six                       1.11.0                   py35_1    conda-forge
snappy                    1.1.7                h777316e_3    defaults
snowballstemmer           1.2.1                      py_1    conda-forge
sortedcollections         1.0.1                      py_1    conda-forge
sortedcontainers          2.0.4                      py_1    conda-forge
sphinx                    1.7.5                    py35_0    conda-forge
sphinxcontrib             1.0              py35h45f5ca3_1    defaults
sphinxcontrib-websupport  1.1.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
spyder                    3.3.1                    py35_1    conda-forge
spyder-kernels            0.2.6                      py_0    conda-forge
sqlalchemy                1.2.11           py35hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.23.1               h35aae40_0    defaults
statsmodels               0.9.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
sympy                     1.2                      py35_0    conda-forge
tblib                     1.3.2                      py_1    conda-forge
terminado                 0.8.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.3.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.7                hcb92d03_3    defaults
toolz                     0.9.0                      py_0    conda-forge
tornado                   5.1              py35hfa6e2cd_1    conda-forge
traitlets                 4.3.2                    py35_0    conda-forge
trimesh                   2.32.10                    py_0    conda-forge
twisted                   18.7.0           py35hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
typed-ast                 1.1.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
typing                    3.6.4                    py35_2    conda-forge
unicodecsv                0.14.1                     py_1    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.23                     py35_1    conda-forge
vc                        14.1                 h0510ff6_3    defaults
vs2015_runtime            15.5.2                        3    defaults
wcwidth                   0.1.7                      py_1    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                    py35_0    conda-forge
werkzeug                  0.14.1                     py_0    conda-forge
wheel                     0.31.1                   py35_1    conda-forge
widgetsnbextension        3.4.0                    py35_0    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.0.1                    py35_1    conda-forge
win_unicode_console       0.5                      py35_0    conda-forge
wincertstore              0.2                      py35_2    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    defaults
wrapt                     1.10.11                  py35_0    conda-forge
xlrd                      1.1.0                      py_2    conda-forge
xlsxwriter                1.0.7                      py_0    conda-forge
xlwings                   0.11.8                   py35_0    conda-forge
xlwt                      1.3.0                      py_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.1.7                hc54c509_2    defaults
zeromq                    4.2.5                hc6251cf_0    defaults
zict                      0.1.3                      py_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11               h8395fce_2    defaults
zope.interface            4.5.0            py35hfa6e2cd_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: What happens when you do `conda update conda` from a non-admin prompt?

Comment: @darthbith same results as admin prompt.

Comment: And what is that result, specifically? `UnsatisfiableError`?

Comment: @darthbith It prints `All requested packages already installed` and `==> WARNING: A newer version of conda exists. <==` along with some other info about `conda`.

Comment: Is there any chance you have 2 condas installed on the computer?

Comment: @darthbith Not as far as I can find. I've searched through windows explorer. Don't know how else to look for it since there is no `which` command on Win10.

Answer (score 1):

I believe I had the same problem. The solution for me was to run:
**conda install anaconda=custom**
before updating the Navigator.

For the explanation, please see:
https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/11966